# How to use pd.read_csv to filter columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have two questions about dataframe**

**Questions:1**
I need to read a csv file as a DataFrame. The original files as [this](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD).
I Would like to only read data of 2005~2015. And I need to add 'Country Name' as index.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
GPD = (pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', skiprows=4, index_col='Country Name', usecols=(0,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59))
  .replace({"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran","Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"}))
```

But I meet error as:

> TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'

How do I correct my code?

**Questions:2**
I need to calculate GDP over the last 10 years for each country. This should be return a Series named avgGDP with 15 countries and their average GDP sorted in descending order.

I have no idea how to do with it.

Would guys could help with this two questions? Thanks.

Comment: *I need to calculate GDP over the last 10 years for each country.*...isn't that the dataset?

Answer (score 4):

Consider replacing *Country Name* values then setting it as index:

```
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', skiprows=4, usecols=[0] + list(range(50,60)))

GDP['Country Name'] = GDP['Country Name'].replace(to_replace=["Korea, Rep.", "Iran, Islamic Rep.", "Hong Kong SAR, China"],
                                                  value=["South Korea", "Iran", "Hong Kong"])    
GDP = GDP.set_index('Country Name')
```

As for the average GDP, consider melting dataframe with `melt` into long format and then running `groupby`. However, these steps require *Country Name* as a named column and not index (so commented out):

```
# GDP = GDP.set_index('Country Name')

mGDP = pd.melt(GDP, id_vars='Country Name', var_name='Year', value_name='GDP')

mGDP = mGDP.groupby(['Country Name'])['GDP'].agg({'AvgGDP':'mean'}).sort_values('AvgGDP', ascending=False)

#                                                           AvgGDP
# Country Name                                                    
# World                                               6.735456e+13
# High income                                         4.600995e+13
# OECD members                                        4.518469e+13
# Post-demographic dividend                           4.298146e+13
# IDA & IBRD total                                    2.208337e+13
# Europe & Central Asia                               2.155501e+13
# Low & middle income                                 2.135025e+13
# Middle income                                       2.104455e+13
# IBRD only                                           2.038699e+13
# European Union                                      1.748398e+13
# North America                                       1.723858e+13
# East Asia & Pacific                                 1.719137e+13
# Upper middle income                                 1.653071e+13
# United States                                       1.562297e+13
# Late-demographic dividend                           1.441396e+13
# Euro area                                           1.282312e+13
# East Asia & Pacific (excluding high income)         8.697876e+12
# East Asia & Pacific (IDA & IBRD countries)          8.681259e+12
# Early-demographic dividend                          8.418026e+12
# China                                               6.934351e+12
# Latin America & Caribbean                           5.146274e+12
# Japan                                               4.959066e+12
```

And some clean up is required since there are continent and region GDP totals and not just countries:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By your method, I could figure it out how to read csv files from one part to another part. @Parfait

Answer (score 3):

You can do this your way, but I would recommend that you use the [`pandas_datareader`](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package for this. You can follow the guide on that web page to install it. Once you've got it installed, you can use the following to get what you want:

```
from pandas_datareader import wb
import pandas as pd


# Get 2-character ISO country names
all_countries = [x for x in wb.country_codes if len(x) == 2]

df_list = []

for country in all_countries:
    try:
        df_list.append(wb.download(indicator='NY.GDP.MKTP.CD', country = country, start=2005, end=2015, errors='ignore'))
    except ValueError:
        pass


GDP = pd.concat(df_list)

print GDP.head()

#               NY.GDP.MKTP.CD
# country year                
# Andorra 2015             NaN
#         2014             NaN
#         2013    3.248925e+09
#         2012    3.146152e+09
#         2011    3.427023e+09

avgGDP = GDP.groupby(level=0).mean().sort_values(by='NY.GDP.MKTP.CD', ascending = False)

print avgGDP.head()

#                 NY.GDP.MKTP.CD
# country                       
# United States     1.539304e+13
# China             6.511771e+12
# Japan             4.923866e+12
# Germany           3.471651e+12
# United Kingdom    2.704811e+12
```

You can still do it your way, but you may need to do a bit more work:

```
GDP1 = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', 
    skiprows=4, 
    index_col ='Country Name', 
    usecols=(0,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59))

GDP1 = GDP1.reset_index().replace({'Country Name': {"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", 
    "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
    "Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"}}).set_index('Country Name')

GDP1 = pd.melt(GDP1.reset_index(), 
    id_vars= 'Country Name', 
    var_name='Year', 
    value_name='GDP').set_index(['Country Name','Year'])

avgGDP1 = GDP1.groupby(level=0).mean().sort_values(by='GDP', ascending = False)

print avgGDP1.head()

#                                     GDP
# Country Name                           
# World                      6.735456e+13
# High income                4.600995e+13
# OECD members               4.518469e+13
# Post-demographic dividend  4.298146e+13
# IDA & IBRD total           2.208337e+13
```

As you can see, it's much harder trying to get the output through downloading the file directly. So the `pandas_datareader` package is really handy here.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's great! I didn't know `pandas_datareader` can parse `World Bank` data - now i do.

Comment: @Edward try it. You can get data for just countries, excluding extra regions.